# Can we lower the barrier for good reviewers to access the close queue?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, closed-questions

Yet again, the [Close Vote queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review) has reached over 10K today (3<sup>rd</sup> June), and it's gradually rising (suprise suprise).

So instead of simply suggesting to lower the rep required to access the CVQ for *everyone*, why not lower the requirement by `X` percent for users with, for example, a <5% failed audit rate, maybe the lower the failed audit rate the higher `X` will be?

Comment: Which review stat(s) would you use for this? Just because someone is good at reviewing suggested edits it doesn't mean they are automatically good at reviewing closures.

Comment: @ChrisF I was thinking on the lines of the user's declined flagging history + first post/late answer failed audit rate.

Comment: @ChrisF: Your comment encouraged me to actually post here on meta. Why not use *all* the review stats at hand and try to predict efficiency?

Comment: but the failure rate is not exposed anywhere so this would require exposing it to the public which I don't necessarily think is a great idea...

Comment: @mehow I didn't mention anything about public display the stats. Just as long as the stats can be privately calculated by the site's servers.

Comment: @Sam since it's not exposed it would require a significant development time to actually implement such a feature that's all I am saying. Would it be worth investing so much dev-time just for this feature-request? I feel that you have demonstrated an idea in your post but forgot to fully justify its usefulness.

Comment: I'd thought about suggesting this, as a user that spends a lot more time reviewing, editing and flagging than asking or answering questions - giving close review privs to people with some absurdly high number of both successful reviews and helpful flags. Seems to me like it'd be giving close review privs to exactly those people best suited for it, and would, thus, increase the number of people who can help close without worrying the admins whether it was being given out to the wrong people (as just lowering the rep requirement would.)

Comment: @ChrisF Just because someone has 3K reputation doesn't mean they are automatically good at reviewing closures, either...

Comment: Now at over 11k, and rising.... I'd be happy to help out. *shrug* Oh well.

Comment: About to hit 13k... and rising....

Comment: It might be quite hard to find the "perfect" way to define who can (or cannot) access review queues based on stats only. Does apply to a lot of community sites other than SO too.

Answer (score 44):

I like the idea, but:

- I'd suggest we purely use close flags and success rate of that (you also need to have flagged at least a certain number of posts already).

  As Chris mentioned, just because someone is good at reviewing suggested edits it doesn't mean they are automatically good at reviewing closures, not to mention that the other queues don't have particularly good audits (AFAIK), so not failing too many audits there doesn't say much.

  To be honest, this actually seems like a better barrier than reputation - just because you managed to get 3k reputation, doesn't say much about your ability to judge off-topicness. We could even completely get rid of the reputation barrier and just use this.

  But there's is a bit of a risk in that it's fairly easy to game flags - you can flag based purely on clear attributes of a question (without really looking at the content) and get everything approved.

  I realize close flags are a bit of a problem given the size of the close vote queue (is it still?) - not sure how to deal with that - possibly have flags expire (and treat it as if it was never cast), but keep the question in the close vote queue.
- Users could perhaps be given an "internship" (there's probably a better word, just can't think of it now).

  They are allowed to start reviewing, but none of their reviews actually count - it's purely to determine if their reviews are consistent with others' and to check if they can consistently pass audits.

  We could keep extending the period of the internship while they keep failing audits or are reviewing inconsistently with other reviewers.

  If this is put into place, we could extend this to users who fail audits (and would currently get banned) (either they go straight onto the internship, or they go onto it after the appropriate ban)
- We need better chosen audits.

  Both of the above depend on users currently reviewing actually doing a good job, which isn't easy to judge or enforce with a broken audit system.

  Some are ridiculously easy, some are next to impossible to judge and plenty are just wrong (mostly "should stay open" reviews on off topic questions AFAIK).

  Given that the same audit can be given to just about everyone, it probably won't be too much work to pick a few audits by hand (perhaps in addition to the automated ones, but carrying a much higher weight)
- We need an automated mechanism to deal with bad audits (if we're going to stick to auto-generated ones).

  Perhaps we can have users flag it, which lead to a few experienced users getting it - if the action taken by them is consistent, it stays an audit, perhaps switching from "should stay open" to "should be closed" - if it's not consistent, it's removed as an audit.

  Or, since we can just give the same audit to multiple reviewers, we can just look at the failed rate of an audit to determine if it's good, but that could just mean that it's hard, not that it's bad - perhaps we should have a moderator make the final call.

  (Or is there already something like this? If so, it might be good to indicate this on the "STOP! Look and Listen" message, as to prevent people from posting Meta discussions about it and having them get frustrated with failing incorrect audits ... and it should be wiped from the record of whomever failed it if the audit was found to be bad, if this isn't already done)

Comment: Doesn't the system decline all flags if any are declined? Such as a spam flag getting declined will decline other flags on the post as well?

Comment: @JoeW I suspect most of the close flags don't actually have any corresponding flags cast on the same post (so no flags on the post gets processed), and, while what you say is true about flags in general, I wouldn't be surprised if the close flags are separate, given that the close system is somewhat distinct from the flag system.

Comment: @JoeW: that's no longer the case, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81407/dismiss-flags-on-the-same-posts-with-different-validities/225779#225779

Comment: SAY NO TO UNPAID INTERNSHIPS! :P

Answer (score 12):

Part of the problem is that, ironically, people who are willing to spend a lot of time reviewing end up having much slower reputation growth after they become eligible for the first few queues.  As a result, it takes longer for them to be eligible to cast close votes and there's a bigger chance of them getting burned out on reviews first.

A solution may be to reduce the gap between the reputation required for the first review queues and the close queue.  This could be done either by reducing the reputation required for the close queue or, ironically, by increasing the reputation required for the earlier queues.

Answer (score -3):

I am a complete outsider and pretty new to the systems, but I feel that SO is making to little use of the potential power of the data at its hand.

Why do you need *any* criteria? Why not (summary:)

- define a loss function (combination of "emptying the queue" and "errors in the process", that is, false positives and false negatives)
- fix a time sample of all the data
- try to predict "mistakes quota" of people based on any observables you have. Obviously, you can focus on the regions where you want to be more permissive: No need to include "has gold medal" as a regressor if these guys already access the queue. See *caveat* below
- fit in your regression results into the defined loss function and minimize it
- Voilà, you have the optimal (w.r.t. your loss function) access criteria for the close queue (or whatever the object is)

Finally, since you restricted on the time sample, you can even simulate "what if these people were allowed to access the queue" using the remainder of time in order to get an idea of how good the idea would work.

**Caveat**

Importantly, *There is no real data on how well did people do that do not satisfy the "close queue"*. That's the whole point, right? How good *would* they be. Say, there is this user *A* who

- has been registered for 100 days
- has posted 5 posts with average 3 points
- has edited 8 questions and has all of the edits confirmed.

No one knows how good this user would be at the close queue, right? But, you have data on user *B* and user *C*, who both looked like *A* 1 year ago, and one of them is doing really well now in the queue and one is not. Essentially, the question you would answer is

**How likely is it that this *A* turns out to become like *B*, not *C*, and what are the costs if he actually turned out to be *C*?**

Since you can always exclude someone from the queue if he turns out to be bad, I'd think that the costs are not too high.

**Downside**

While the idea of implementation is very clean, it may be difficult to transmit to new users ("A likelihood estimator predicted me to be a good user, wtf?").

Also, it may make maintenance more difficult: It will not be immediately clear any more "why exactly" someone has specific rights.

**Potential Downside**

I don't believe this, but just for completeness: It is a step away from "fairness" towards "efficiency". People do not get rights because they have earned them, but because the system expects them to be useful with these rights.

Comment: User A: "I have to behave like x to be promoted." Let the gaming begin!

Comment: Sebastian: Given that "x" is most likely a set of actions that we like users to do (since "B" is a "good" user), why not? User A: "I need to have at least 10 answers with on average 4 reputation points, let's get it on" - why not?

Comment: Moreover: The criteria should be updated over time. If certain treats seem to be "faked" by low users quickly in order to get rights, this should reduce the power of those treats in the prediction mechanism (since those users will not have good results in the queue and "down vote" those treats) and make other treats (perhaps those that are not copy-able that easily) more favorable.

Comment: This assumes that you can accurately predict bad behavior.  You can't.  This assumes that bad behavior will generally be caught manually when it isn't caught automatically.  It generally can't be (at least not on the scales of the bad actors that there are).  This was effectively proven with all of the troubles that the suggested edit queue has had throughout its lifetime.

Comment: Servy: You surprise me, to say the least. Either you have a very narrow definition of "accurately", or you imply that even you, a 80k user could suddenly go crazy and become bad. Second, "caught manually" - why not automatically? If you predict someone to be good and give him more power than he deserves, you can immediately update your prior once he misuses his rights and remove the rights. I don't know the full trouble of the suggested edit queue, but this is what it boils down to: If you want to have an automatic system of rights, you need to have automatic fallbacks (removals) as well.