# Are there too few moderators? I have over 50% "aged away" flags

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions

I have raised 78 flags where 31 of them are "aged away" and 16 "waiting" which will "age away" too, I suppose.

30% from "aged away" flags were "duplicate" flags which are hard to find and raise. In such case **there is no reason to spent time to raise "Duplication" flags**.

I suppose there should be some way to review the helpfulness of raised flags by others, shouldn't it? If so, how is this process done?

Although [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335820/2675154) is similar, I think that it shouldn't be common to have so many "aged away" flags. It is very uncommon to do work which just "ages away". In my case it is 50% of my work.

Comment: They are probably close flags; those aren't handled by ♦ moderators, but the Close Votes review queue.

Comment: @Glorfindel: [I have stopped raising certain flag types because I know they will stay pending and nobody will take action](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287165/why-were-my-older-close-flags-aged-away#comment161004_287165) and [YOU WASTED YOUR TIME](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287165/why-were-my-older-close-flags-aged-away#comment161061_287211). Two year is left but nothing is done...

Comment: @Glorfindel It is **very uncommon** to do work which just "aged away".

Comment: Basically, there is too much crap and too few people (i.e. >3k users, not just ♦ moderators) to handle it. That's why initiatives like [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) exist.

Comment: @Glorfindel: So the required score should be lowered in other case you just lose reviewer at all. See links above

Comment: No, people who care about the quality of the site should work hard and earn more reputation :)

Comment: @EugenKonkov: [There have already been similar requests](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258162/2675154).

Comment: Consider two things: 1) The kinds of flags you're talking about aren't handled by moderators (as already mentioned). 2) There is a consensus required for a reason; just because *you* think something should be handled a certain way doesn't mean everybody agrees. Perhaps your flags are just ageing away because they were invalid to begin with. (Not saying this is necessarily the case specifically for you; but do consider it as a possibility.)

Comment: *It is **very uncommon** to do work which just "aged away"* [citation needed]. Every piece of code I wrote 15 years ago "aged away" and has been rewritten or removed (I hope).

Comment: @Glorfindel It seems I just stop to raise 'Duplicate' flags. Because of it is useless time wasting: 10%. At least currently